# postgresql composite type записать данные запроса

Tags: postgresql

С помощью запроса беру данные: дата, сумма, заказы. Хочу записать все данные, которые взял, через запрос в composite type, и вывести все данные. Все это хочу реализовать через функцию. Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Конкретики бы добавить. Покажите запрос; поясните, что хотите от функции (возможно, пример того, как вы хотите ее использовать).

Answer (score 2):

### Короткий ответ

Пример подобной функции, которая берёт данные из таблицы goods, сохраняет их в поле report (составного типа) таблицы report и затем возвращает эти данные.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION write_goods_to_report_and_return_them() 
    RETURNS setof goods AS $$
DECLARE
    r record;
BEGIN

    for r in select * from goods
    loop                       
        insert into report(report) values ((r.amount, r.orders_count, r.date));
        return next r;                      
    end loop;                  
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

### Развёрнутый ответ

**1. Создаём таблицу из которой будем брать данные для примера.**

```
create table goods (
    id           serial primary key,
    amount       integer not null default 0,
    orders_count integer not null default 0,
    date         date    not null default now()
);
```

**2. Заполняем её данными.**

```
insert into goods(amount, orders_count, date) values(120, 4, now());
insert into goods(amount, orders_count, date) values(90, 3, now());
```

**3. Создаём составной тип данных** ([composite type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rowtypes.html)).

```
create type reports as (
    amount       integer,
    orders_count integer,
    date         date
);
```

**4. Создаём таблицу с полем reports, в которую будем записывать выборку.**

```
create table report (
    id     serial primary key,
    report reports
);
```

**5. Создаём PL/pgSQL функцию, которая будет записывать выборку в поле report 
типа reports.** ([Подробнее о PL/pgSQL функциях](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql.html))

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION write_goods_to_report_and_return_them() RETURNS setof goods AS $$
DECLARE
    r record;
BEGIN

    for r in select * from goods
    loop                       
        insert into report(report) values ((r.amount, r.orders_count, r.date));
        return next r;                      
    end loop;                  
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**6. Проверяем работу.**

**6.1. В отчетах пусто.**

```
select * from report;
 id | report 
----+--------
(0 rows)
```

**6.2. Проверяем возвращаемые значения из нашей функции.**

```
select * from write_goods_to_report_and_return_them();
 id | amount | orders_count |    date    
----+--------+--------------+------------
  1 |    120 |            4 | 2016-01-21
  2 |     90 |            3 | 2016-01-21
(2 rows)
```

**6.3. В отчетах теперь также хранится результат работы функции.**

```
select * from report;
 id |       report       
----+--------------------
  1 | (120,4,2016-01-21)
  2 | (90,3,2016-01-21)
(2 rows)
```